# Playwright project dependencies not part of setup definition

Tags: playwright

When following this [guide for using dependencies](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-projects#dependencies) I get an error that

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dependencies' does not exist in type 'Project<PlaywrightTestOptions, PlaywrightWorkerOptions>'.
```

I'm using Playwright `1.39.0` and can't figure this out.

Is this a bug in the typescript definition?

[image]

Comment: turns out I hadn't updated playwright - closing

Answer (score 0):

Needed to update my playwright version. I hadn't run `npm i` on the right directory.